# Table with merged cells

Tags: tables

I would like to have a table to looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{5cm} | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
    & Taylor expansion &  & Power series \\ \hline
     & $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x-1)^{k}+o((x-a)^{n})$$ &  & $$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_k(x-1)^{k}$$     \\ \hline
   Order  & $DL_{n}(0)$  &  $DL_{5}(0)$  &  \\ \hline
   exp(x) & $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}+o(x^n) $$  & $$1+x+\drac{x^2}{2}+ $$  & $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$$ \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makecell}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | *{4}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}|}}
    \hline
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Taylor expansion}    & Power series \\ \hline
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\displaystyle
            f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x-1)^{k}+o((x-a)^{n})$}
                                                &   f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_k(x-1)^{k}    \\ 
    \hline
Order   &   DL_{n}(0)   &   DL_{5}(0)           &                                       \\ 
    \hline
$\exp(x)$   &   \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}+o(x^n)  
                        &   1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+  & \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}         \\   
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**
Use of `$$ ... $$` is in LaTeX deprecate. Instead it you should use `\[ ... \]` or `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`. Since all this math environments don't work in column types `c`, `l` and `r`, instead them I use `$\displaystyle ... $`. For shorter code I modified columns type to `>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}` so the whoole column is in math mode (except `\multicolumn`s). Therefore the text in header of the last column had to be in wrote as `\text{Power series}`.

More vertical space around cells content is obtained by macros `\setcellgapes{5pt}` and `\makegapedcells` from package `makecell`.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Taylor expansion} & Power series \\ \hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x-1)^{k}+o((x-a)^{n})$} & $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_k(x-1)^{k}$ \\ \hline
  Order & $DL_{n}(0)$ & $DL_{5}(0)$ & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, not really. `;-)` When cells are merged, the excess goes on the last merged column.

Comment: @egreg I am not sure I understand what you mean by "excess". Do you refer to columns DLn and DL5 to be of unequal size?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

With that environment, which is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of the package `array`), you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the command `\Block`. Then the key `hvlines` draws all the rules, excepted in the blocks (created by `\Block`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=5pt]
          & \Block{1-2}{Taylor expansion} && Power series \\ 
          & \Block{1-2}{$\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x-1)^{k}+o((x-a)^{n})$} &&  $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0} a_k(x-1)^{k}$ \\ 
Order     & $\text{DL}_{n}(0)$ & $\text{DL}_{5}(0)$ \\ 
$\exp(x)$ & $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}+o(x^n)$ & $\displaystyle 1+x+\cdots+\frac{x^5}{5!}+o(x^5)$  
            & $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}$ \\   
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]